# Is it likely that the Nexus can destroy any ship in the Star Trek Universe?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-generations

In the movie *Star Trek: Generations*, the energy bolts emanating out of the Nexus destroyed two ships and they almost destroyed the Enterprise B.

These energy bolts are apparently very powerful and they are constantly being produced by the Nexus. They will eventually destroy the shield and then the hull of any ship that happens to get too close to the Nexus and/or pulled into it.

Since the Nexus appears to have an endless supply of energy bolts, it seems to me that it has the capability to destroy any ship in the Star Trek Universe, from standard-size ships such as Federation ships, Romulan ships, Dominion ships, etc., to larger ships such as Borg cubes, all the way up to very large ships such as the Whale Probe or V'Ger. Moreover, I don't think any weapon on any ship in the Star Trek Universe can destroy the Nexus.

Is it likely that the Nexus can destroy any ship in the Star Trek Universe?

Comment: The nexus is a force of nature - do you mean that the ships have to deliberately fly into the nexus and stay there for a while? If you expect the ships to fly in and wait for their doom - then sure. If not, then why would they engange with the Nexus anyway?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the two ships it trapped in Generations where small transporter ships, without active shields, and the Enterprise B was underequipped and also did not use its shields. It's hard to say how this would have played out under different circumstances

Comment: @PhilippFlenker, well, look at it this way. Say that a ship's engine were to fail and this ship was adrift in space and then the Nexus comes along and this ship becomes caught in it. In such a scenario, I believe that the Nexus will destroy this ship, even with its shields up, and it most likely can destroy any ship in the Star Trek universe, regardless of how big or powerful that ship may be.

Comment: A bird can peck away a mountain given enough time - so sure, why not

Comment: I bet The Think Tank would be able to survive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No.

The energy bursts are not the main problem of the Nexus, but the gravimetric field:

> **COMM VOICE**: This is the transport ship Lakul. We're caught in some kind of energy distortion. Two ships in our convoy. ...We're trapped in a severe gravimetric distortion. We can't break free. We need immediate help. It' tearing us apart. This is the trans...

(Star Trek: Generations)

This is further backed by the fact that the Enterprise-B is not using its shields throughout the engagement with the Nexus. The process of breaking free seems to be something that most bigger ships of the Star Trek Universe can easily do, all you need is an antimatter discharge, or a deflector dish:

> **SCOTT**: An anti-matter discharge directly ahead might disrupt the field long enough for us to break away.
>   **KIRK**: Photon torpedo?
>   **SCOTT**: Aye sir.
>   **SCIENCE OFFICER**: We're losing main power.
>   **KIRK (OC)**: Load torpedo bays, prepare to fire on my command.
>   **DEMORA**: Captain, ...we don't have any torpedoes.
>   **KIRK**: Don't tell me. ...Tuesday.
>   **LIEUTENANT**: Hull integrity at forty percent.
>   **SCOTT**: Captain, it may be possible to simulate a torpedo blast using a resonance burst from the main deflector dish.

(Star Trek: Generations)

It stands to reason that the Enterprise B would have been able to escape by itself with less damage had it not been underequipped due to the circumstances.

So unless you expect all ships to be pulled in and wait to be pulled apart, it is unlikely that the Nexus can destroy all ships in the Star Trek universe.

Comment: The energy bursts are a big problem though. Both ships are destroyed by bursts and the Enterprise is hit by one and suffers severe damage

Comment: Yes, but all these ships have their shields down at that time (if they even have any shields at all), so it's hard to tell how dangerous they are to a fully equipped, combat-ready Enterprise B.